# mysqli::real_escape_string creates \r\n problems?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where the users use TinyMCE to fill out some information, and that form is then POSTed, and stored in a database.
The problem appears to be that `mysqli::real_escape_string` is turning carriage return line feeds into escaped versions of themselves, and storing them. Well... that is part of the design. But when I re-read the database, and run `stripslashes()` on the data as it is read from the DB, I get output like this:

```
 Here si some good HTML code
 rn
 But you can see
 rn
 that there are annoying
 rn
 "rn" on blank lines between everything.
```

How can I store HTML in the DB, and retrieve it without having this \r\n problem?

Comment: `mysqli::real_escape_string` should do no such thing; `stripslashes()` should never be necessary. Can you show your code?

Comment: Did you try using any encode method before save it in the database

Comment: Why are you running `stripslashes()`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams maybe magic quotes are enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original answer is not categorically out of date.

The modern best solution is to use PDO.

```
$pdo    = new PDO($dsn);
$sql    = "INSERT INTO posts (`foo`) VALUES (?)";
$stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$values = $_POST['text_area'];

$stmt->execute( [ $values ] );
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution would be to remove the CRLF from the data first

```
$str = str_replace("\r\n", "", $str);
```

Be sure to use double quotes so PHP knows to look for CRLF and not a literal `\r\n`

Comment: Or - as every smart guy does, it's better to fix the real issue, not the consequences